# call() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, call

I just found the example as follow code, the fork() function may be implement same as the Array.forEach(). So, my question is: why `thisp` must be passed the fun.call() and why the last argument is `this`.

Hope to receive your kindly support,

```js
if (!Array.prototype.fork) {
    Array.prototype.fork = function(fun /*, thisp*/ ) {
        var len = this.length;
        //console.log(this);
        if (typeof fun != "function")
            throw new TypeError();

        var thisp = arguments[1];
        console.log(thisp);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in this)
                fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
           
var keywords = ["sdfsdf", "dfhgfh", "Học lập trình", "thehalfheart"]

keywords.fork(function(eachName, index) {
    console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName);
}, 'rich');
```

Comment: It is passing `this`, but the code is not using it...

Comment: What is `fork`? Where did you find this example code?

Comment: @Bergi, I reference from a page, I just want to know the mechanism of using parameter `element` and `index` in the function `Array.forEach(function(element, index){})`. I think the `fork()` function above is same as `forEach()`, so, i can understand now.

Comment: From which page? Please link it! Yes, it works like`forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st parameter to [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is what the value of `this` should be *inside* the called function.  The `thisp` parameter seems to be there in case your callback needs a specific context (`this` value) to run - such as a method inside a class.

As for why `this` is passed as the last parameter for `call()`, that's so your callback can get the *original* array as a parameter.  As you see, you don't *need* to use it in your callback, but you can.

```
thisArg = {a:1}
[1,2,3].fork(function(value, index, origArray){
    // origArray will be [1,2,3] in each loop
    // this will be `{a:1}`, because we passed it in as `thisArg`
    // thisArg is optional and will be `null` if not passed
}, thisArg);
```

For reference, see the docs for `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: thanks for your support, I got the idea now: the first `this` is for specify the context of `this` in case using of callback function, the second `this` is just redundant in that case.